# return true or false if at least one entity in list A matches an entity in list B

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists:

```
List<int> a = new List() { 1, 2, 3 }
List<int> b = new List() { 4, 5, 6 }
```

I have this method...

```
public bool DoesExist(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{
    foreach (var item in a)
    {
        if (b.Contains(item)) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

the method should return false for DoesExist(a, b)

if b was {3, 4, 5, 6} it should return true...

is there a cleaner one-liner way to do this in Linq?

thanks

Comment: Look at the intersect method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility with LINQ:

```
return a.Intersect(b).Any();
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

```
return a.Any(b.Contains);
```

Credit to [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)...  Give the trial a go.  You'll wonder how you lived without it.  No link - just a satisfied customer...

Comment: @SLaks Admittedly, that's one area of my knowledge I need to brush up on.  Isn't the OP code also O(n^2), so this is a one line replacement for it still.  I'd need to dive into the innards of `Intersect` to find out what that's doing to see if it's better in that respect.

Comment: Yes.  `Intersect` uses a hash set.